# Not able to Login to IMAP server for office365 account via GoDaddy

Tags: office365, imap, basic-authentication, godaddy-api, chilkat-email

I am trying to configure a client's office365/GoDaddy account to an email client using IMAP. But it fails to Login to IMAP server. Below is the error:

```
ChilkatLog:
  Login:
    DllDate: Dec 21 2018
    ChilkatVersion: 9.5.0.76
    UnlockPrefix: XXXX.CB1022022
    Architecture: Little Endian; 32-bit
    Language: .NET 4.5 / x86 / VS2013
    VerboseLogging: 0
    loginX:
      greeting: * OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready. [TABPADQAUAAxADIAMwBDAEEAMAAxADgAOQAuAEcAQgBSAFAAMQAyADMALgBQAFIATwBEAC4ATwBVAFQATABPAE8ASwAuAEMATwBNAA==]

      authenticateLogin:
        loginImap:
          ConnectionType: SSL/TLS
        --loginImap
        isOK:
          serverResponse: aaab NO LOGIN failed.
        --isOK
      --authenticateLogin
    --loginX
    Failed.
  --Login
--ChilkatLog
```

I've tried login using app Password too, but No Luck. I even tried disabling 2 factor oauth for the account. I've configured the office365 account to my email client earlier without hassle, not sure what is going wrong here.

IMAP details: outlook.office365.com
Imap Port: 993 ,TLS

SMTP is working fine.

Please suggest how to fix it.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `serverResponse: aaab NO LOGIN failed.` show your code snippet of course anonymize them before posting

Answer (score 1):

As of January 2023, Microsoft has disabled Basic Authentication for IMAP. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/deprecation-of-basic-authentication-exchange-online

There is no way to re-enable it for IMAP or any of the other protocols listed on that page. (although for sending emails, they still support SMTP AUTH but you must specifically enable it)

So, you need to change your code to authenticate with OAuth 2.0. For your specific case, it looks like you are using the Chilkat Mail library. I am not sure what language your code is written in, but you should be able to follow one of these tutorials: https://cknotes.com/office365-modern-authentication-for-imap-pop3-and-smtp/

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify that IMAP protocol is enabled for your user.
For MS outlook account, you can follow below step to check/enable your user for IMAP protocol.

1. Login to https://admin.microsoft.com/ with your admin account.
2. Go to left panel , Click on Users , Active user , click on your user
3. Go to newly opened right side pane , Click on Mail tab
4. Click on 'Manage email apps'

You can see here whether your user is allowed to use IMAP protocol.

You can refer this video to enable IMAP protocol for microsoft/outllok type account . https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lMMquUUpKQE